# Qt5 build as shared library on macos using cmake and vcpkg

Tags: qt, cmake, vcpkg

Building the `Qt` library as shared library using `cmake` and `vcpkg` on the macOS Monterey(version 12.2.1) fails. Using the default `VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE` though (i.e. static), builds the library and makes it usable successfully. The issue only happens when I try to build it as a shared library.

The full toolset that I'm using:

- macOS Monterey - 12.2.1 (21D62).
- `Xcode` 13.3(Build version 13E113).
- `cmake` version 3.22.3.
- `vcpkg` tag - 2022.03.10(`af2287382b1991dbdcb7e5112d236f3323b9dd7a`).
- `Qt` version set implicitly by this `vcpkg` tag - `5.15.3`.

On my `PreLoad.cmake` file - the following code is included:

```
...
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-osx")
set(VCPKG_HOST_TRIPLET "x64-osx")
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64)
...
```

When running `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` the Qt library (eventually) builds successfully. However, when I'm trying to build it as a shared library to be later dynamically linked to my code by adding this snippet to my `PreLoad.cmake:`

```
if((${PORT} MATCHES "qt5-base") OR (${PORT} MATCHES "qt5-tools"))
    set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE dynamic)
else()
    set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
endif()
```

the `vcpkg` install process fails with this error:

```
-- Running vcpkg install - failed
CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:834 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  /Users/avibiton/Dev/main/build/vcpkg-manifest-install.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:124 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Inspecting the `vcpkg-manifest-install.log` file and from there into `vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/config-x64-osx-dbg-err.log` file, I came across this error message:

```
ERROR: debug-only framework builds are not supported. Configure with -no-framework if you want a pure debug build.
```

So I went to this file `vcpkg/ports/qt5-base/portfile.cmake` and tried to append the `-no-framework` flag to the `CORE_OPTIONS` variable like this:

```
...
## 3rd Party Libs
list(APPEND CORE_OPTIONS
    -system-zlib
    -system-libjpeg
    -system-libpng
    -system-freetype
    -system-pcre
    -system-doubleconversion
    -system-sqlite
    -system-harfbuzz
    -icu
    -no-vulkan
    -no-angle # Qt does not need to build angle. VCPKG will build angle!
    -no-glib
    -no-framework # This is my change
    )
...
```

But this change turn out to be a rabbit-hole of it self :(

If anyone has succeeded building `Qt` as a shared library on macos using cmake and vcpkg, I'll be grateful for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `Qt` and other `vcpkg` dependencies built in debug configuration you could also set the `VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE` in your `PreLoad.cmake`

```
...    
set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
...
```

If your other ports need to be built in debug configuration, you could probably also set this on a per port basis as you did with `VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE`

```
...
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
if(PORT MATCHES "qt5-")
    set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE dynamic)
    set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
endif()
...
```

As this setting will most likely break Windows builds, you should rather use a custom triplet that will only be used for macOS builds instead of a `PreLoad.cmake` that is potentially used for all platforms, including Windows.
You can find an example for how to do this in the vcpkg docs https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/examples/overlay-triplets-linux-dynamic.html.